# How to modify and update Visual Studio Object

Tags: c++, object, visual-studio-2019

I want to delete all the object that is not used now.
I used Visual Studio 2019.

When I search Object Browser, It gets to me some strange struct or class that I modified of name.

For example, first I define a structure as

```
typedef struct stOutput
{
    double dDirtyPrice_CumInt;
    double dDM;
    //...
    double dYield;
} stOutput
```

Later I changed this definition to

```
typedef struct stOutput_New
{
    double dAI;
    //...
    long   lObservStartDate;
} stOutput_New
```

However, the object browser shows to me just
`stOutput`.
There is no `stOutput_New`.

Also I put my cursor on 'stOutput_New' and push 'F12' then it locates my view some strange area.
There are even no 'stOutput_New'

Now, below picture is describing my real situation
[image]

This is 'Class View'
Actually I just use One `stOutput`, but there are so many `stOutput` that has same file path

Also below picture is my 'Object Browser'
[image]

[image]

As you can see the two `stOutput` have different member variables.
And I changed the name from `stOutput` to `stOutput_new` the latter.

But it seems my object browser didn't reflect it.

I tried

1. Project Unload and Reload it
2. Organize the code of Solution and Project
3. Re-Build Solution.

But everything doesn't work.

Please help me

Comment: What do you mean by *"Later I changed this object"*? You provided the definition of a new struct and object of that type; how is that supposed to change the original object (of the original type)?

Comment: @JaMiT I mean I add '_New' to 'typedef struct stOutput' so the output is 'typedef struct stOutput_New' and delete 'DirtyPrice_CumInt' of 'double dDirtyPrice_CumInt;' then Add 'AI' to it. So the output 'double dAI;'

Comment: If I understand you correctly, what you did would be more accurately described as changing the **definition** of the object, rather than changing the object itself. Err... I just realized I misread that definition. (Sorry, that excessively verbose C-style definition caught me off-guard.) You did not define an object, but a type. So more accurate would be describing what you did as changing the **definition** of the *type*.

Comment: @JaMiT Sorry for making misunderstand. I missed many details. As you mentioned definition of the type is right. not object.

Answer (score 1):

In vs2019, I defined the structure exactly like yours according to your description, and then changed the structure according to your description. My object browser did not have the problem you described. If you are sure that your code does not repeat the definition of structure and other problems, I suggest you reinstall or repair VS.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsjjg.png)